# Como usar o tipo TBitmap32 (Delphi) em uma DLL chamada em C++?

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

Olá!

Estou precisando criar uma *DLL* em *Delphi*, para usá-la em um programa escrito em *C++*. Esta *DLL* deve manipular uma imagem (obtida por meio do *path* passado como parâmetro da função).
No entanto, estou com problemas na etapa de carregar a imagem dentro da *DLL*; o programa quebra quando há qualquer chamada relacionada à imagem.
Estou usando uma variável do tipo `TImage32` (`img : TImage32`); a essa variável será atribuído um `TBitmap32` (`img.Bitmap := TBitmap32.Create`) e, finalmente, a imagem deve ser carregada usando `img.Bitmap.LoadFromFile(path)`.

**Testes que eu fiz:**

- Executei a *DLL*, a partir do *C++*, com partes que não usam imagens. Isso **funcionou corretamente**;
- Executei o mesmo trecho, inserindo a linha `img.Bitmap := TBitmap32.Create;`. Isso **falhou na linha mencionada**.

Existe algum truque para usar imagens em *DLL* no Delphi?

**OBS1:** eu não postei código, pois não é esse, realmente o problema.

**OBS2:** a minha experiência com *Delphi* é nula, bem como com criação de *DLL*.

Muito obrigado!

Comment: A princípio não é para ter grandes segredos. Chega a apresentar qual exceção esta acontecendo? Caso não estoure a exceção claramente na sua aplicação em C++ é possível salvar a exceção em um log em arquivo para ter mais detalhes do que esta acontecendo.

Comment: A imagem é um arquivo no teu computador, né? O path está correto? O arquivo está no formato esperado (no caso, Bitmap 32 bits por pixel)? Não sou expert em delphi, mas quando lido com imagens, esses são os erros mais comuns...

Comment: Não deveria ser: "img := TBitmap32.Create;"?

Comment: Na tua OBS1 não te estás a precipitar? o mais provavel é ser do codigo... nao há truques nas DLLS. o mais que podia acontecer era diferenças nos tipos de dados de entrada das funçoes. Por exemplo com o C# é mais dificil, em principio com o C++ seria direto

Answer (score 0):

Pelo visto esta utilizando uma bliblioteca de terceiros, nesse ponto fica complicado ajudar, mas em teoria foi criado com base da **TImage** padrão.

Se for o caso a criação esta com erro e o problema esta exatamente ai, será gerado uma exceção e sua DLL não possui tratamento.

Tente utilizar o **TImage** nativo seguindo esse formato:

```
var
  vTeste: TImage;
begin
  vTeste := TImage.Create(Self);
  vTeste.Picture.Bitmap.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\Teste.bmp');
```

Aqui funcionou normalmente.

Observe que, primeiro devemos criar o Objeto, depois alimentar suas propriedades. No seu caso postado acredito que o problema seja exatamente este!